# How to launch Navitel Navigator and pass coordinates

Tags: android, navigator

I can't find a URL format to launch Navitel Navigator to pass coordinates.

It's simple for a Navmii URL.  `navmii://lat,lng` works fine there, but not for Navitel Navigator.

Has anyone found this URL format?

Comment: I can only tell you that the Navitel app does have a scheme registry on `navitel`, so it gets launched whenever you fire a view action with `navitel://` as data `Uri`. Unfortunately, I have no clue what purpose it serves. It could be to start navigation, but could very well be something else too. It doesn't appear to be documented anywhere that I could find.

Comment: Thank you for participating anyway =)